# CORS doesn't allow connection to API even though it is set to all

Tags: node.js

I've ran into a problem where when I host a server with webpack on my local network (Webpack default I suppose), on the laptop that the front-end server is being run, everything works when connecting through **localhost** or the **IPv4**. When trying to connect to the website through **IPv4** on my desktop I get this error.

> - createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
> - at createError (createError.js:16)
> - at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)

My CORS:

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

I set CORS before any APIs are created. Also my front-end is being ran my webpack since I'm using CRA. Webpack running front-end on network:

[image: Webpack running front-end on network]

Answer (score 0):

Try Using below code :

app.UseCors(builder =>builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com").AllowAnyHeader());

replace http://example.com with the request origin domain address .

Comment: I tried putting in my IPv4 instead of that URL, still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `app.use(cors({origin: 'you localhost eg https'})`)
this will allow only your localhost to access in your server

Comment: I exactly want the opposite of that. When someone else through a different desktop/mobile on the same network try connecting to my website through IPv4, it gives out that error.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Hosted my Node JS server on my network IP instead of my localhost aswell as configured all front-end requests to the network IP. Works like a charm.

```
app.listen(9999, '192.168.1.226', () => {
  console.log(
    'Arclight back-end is online.\n',
    '',
  );
});
```